# "Server not found in Kerberos database" when trying to connect via pyodbc to MS SQL server using Windows Authentication from Linux

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, kerberos

Good day,
I am trying to connect to a MS SQL server database from a Linux host running Python, using Windows authentication.

The MS SQL server is hosted on a machine running **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard**, and the version is **SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit) 12.0.5579.0**.

The Linux host is a Docker container running **Ubuntu 20.04** with **Python 3.9.7** and **pyodbc 40.030**.

Querying the database via pyodbc using SQL password authentication succeeds (so it looks like the ODBC connection is set up correctly), but I need to authenticate on the SQL server using Windows authentication via our domain server, [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-2016).

I tried running `kinit <user>@<domain>`, and it asked for my password (I inserted my Windows Active Directory password there).
When I try to check the ticket that was generated I get:

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001
Default principal: <user>@<domain>

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
02/23/23 12:56:26  02/23/23 22:56:26  krbtgt/<domain>@<domain>
        renew until 02/24/23 12:56:21
```

So it looks like a ticket was generated and it's valid.
I also created an `/etc/krb5.conf` file starting with:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = <domain>
[...]
```

However, when I run python, and I try to establish a connection, using the commands

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> pyodbc.connect('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=<sql_server_name>;DATABASE=<db_name>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;TrustServerCertificate=Yes')
```

I get the error message:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

What am I missing? How can I understand if the problem lies in my host's configuration or in the server's configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's trying to get a Kerberos TGT for the server name and failing. Start by using the full FQDN `yourserver.yourdomain.com` or whatever in the connection string. If that doesn't work, please post the output from `setspn -L yourserver` when run on a Windows machine within the domain.

Comment: @Charlieface Using the full FQDN in the connection string gives the same error (Server not found in Kerberos database (851968)).

Comment: What is the result of `setspn -L yourserver`

Comment: Output of `setspn -L <server>` from a Windows machine within the domain:
`Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=<SERVER>,OU=Secure,OU=Servers,DC=<domain_pt1>,DC=<domain_pt2>,DC=<domain_pt3>:
        TERMSRV/<SERVER>
        TERMSRV/<Server>.<domain_pt1>.<domain_pt2>.<domain_pt3>
        WSMAN/<Server>
        WSMAN/<Server>.<domain_pt1>.<domain_pt2>.<domain_pt3>
        RestrictedKrbHost/<SERVER>
        HOST/<SERVER>
        RestrictedKrbHost/<Server>.<domain_pt1>.<domain_pt2>.<domain_pt3>
        HOST/<Server>.<domain_pt1>.<domain_pt2>.<domain_pt3>`

Comment: Hmm you're missing the `MSSQLSVC` SPN. SQL Server should have added those automatically when it started. You should give it permissions to do so https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver16#Auto and then restart SQL Server. Or you can add it manually, instructions on the same link. Something like `setspn -S MSSQLSvc/yourserver.domain.com` and add to that `:instancename` if not the default SQL Server instance

Comment: Double check the SQL Server error log, you probably have something like `The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name` on startup

Comment: @Charlieface: indeed I see now in the error database log `The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN)[...] Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered.`. I will check how to solve this with the DB administators and post the outcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved: I was able to authenticate via Kerberos after (re)registering the Service Principal Name as suggested by @Charlieface, and described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver16#Auto).
The syntax I used is: `setspn -S MSSQLSvc/<server>.<domain>:<instance> <domain>\<SQL service account>`.

2 important details:

1. I had to add all the SPNs that were mentioned in the SQL error log of the server (`Windows return code: 0x2098<c/> state: 15.`), and use the right SQL service account (can be checked by running `SELECT service_account FROM sys.dm_server_services`)
2. `setspn -S <server>` is not listing all the SPNs, therefore I wasn't able to add the new SPN due to a duplicate being present. I had to use the [`-Q` flag of `setspn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731241(v=ws.11)) to check for already existing "MSSQLSvc" SPNs, deleted them with `setspn -D <spn>` and then ran the command to register the SPNs I needed.

Thanks again @Charlieface!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the Service Principal Names (SPNs) were not registered for SQL Server, so Kerberos negotiation was failing. Kerberos is what underpins Windows Authentication: your local Windows session holds a Kerberos TGT ticket, and is used to get a TGS ticket for the SQL service. This cannot happen if the service is not registered.

SQL Server will register automatically if it has permissions. You can register them manually, as you have now done, but it's often easier to do it automatically.

This process is [fully documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver16#Auto).

> To give permissions to SQL Server startup account to register and modify SPN do the following:
>
> 1. On the Domain Controller machine, start **Active Directory Users and Computers**.
> 2. Select **View** > **Advanced**.
> 3. Under **Computers**, locate the SQL Server computer, and then right-click and select **Properties**.
> 4. Select the **Security** tab and click **Advanced**.
> 5. In the list, if SQL Server startup account is not listed, click **Add** to add it and once it is added do the following:
>
>    1. Select the account and click **Edit**.
>    2. Under **Permissions** select **Validated Write servicePrincipalName**.
>    3. Scroll down and under **Properties** select:
>       **Read servicePrincipalName**
>       **Write servicePrincipalName**
>    4. Click **OK** twice.
> 6. Close **Active Directory Users and Computers**.

Note that it may be difficult to get this to work if SQL Server is running under a local service account. You may want to set it up under a [Managed Service Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview).